# What this kind of syntax called?

Tags: javascript

Where's the documentation for this syntax?
It's a deviation from the classic js.

```
const { history, getListing, params, useInitialValues } = this.props;

const { bookingDates, ...bookingData } = values;
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Comment: Could it be Reactjs?

Answer (score 3):

It is called destructuring, checkout [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Answer (score 1):

This is the syntax for [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). It is an `ES6` feature.